# FULLTEXT search using InnoDB

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb, versioning, myisam

I'm trying to add FULLTEXT index to an existing table, but I'm getting the following error.

1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

The query that I'm using is:

```
alter table <table name> add FULLTEXT INDEX (column name(s))
```

The same query seems to work on my localhost. 
My db engine is InnoDB for both localhost and live server.

Show create table displays:

```
CREATE TABLE `xxx` (
`name1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`city1` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`area1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`add1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`cont1` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`gen` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`landm` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`mo` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`passwd` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`exp` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`qual` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`location_map` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
`email_v` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
`v` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
PRIMARY KEY (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: `Show create table xxx`, and `show table status`

Comment: @DrewPierce edited the post

Comment: still waiting your answer to @olliejones version question

Answer (score 4):

InnoDB first offered FULLTEXT capabilities in MySQL version 5.6.4.  It seems likely that your server is running an earlier version of MySQL than that. (Hosting vendors, especially the inexpensive ones, are notorious for this.)

Use this query to find the versions of various subsystems.

```
 show variables like "%version%";
```

Comment: my host's version is 5.5.41 :( Is there a way out?

Comment: 5.5.41 came out in Nov, 2014 as part of the 5.5 version, but is mostly bug fixes, not feature additions such as FULLTEXT.  5.6.4 came out in Dec, 2011 as an early release of 5.6, but was "not ready for primetime".  5.6.4 roughly matches 5.5.18 in bug fixes.

Comment: You could use MyISAM's FULLTEXT.  But there will be [minor incompatibilities](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#fulltext) when you upgrade.  It is OK to have some tables be MyISAM, some InnoDB.  You might "vertically partition" your current table to move just the text (plus an id) to a MyISAM table.